# Set the duplicated values as NA grouped by another variable in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a toy `DT` shown below

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(2020)
z <- runif(12)
(DT <- data.table(x=rep(c('F', 'M'), each=6), y=rep(rep(c('a', 'b'), each=3), 2), z=z))

    x y           z
 1: F a 0.646902839
 2: F a 0.394225758
 3: F a 0.618501814
 4: F b 0.476891136
 5: F b 0.136097186
 6: F b 0.067384386
 7: M a 0.129152617
 8: M a 0.393117930
 9: M a 0.002582699
10: M b 0.620205954
11: M b 0.764414018
12: M b 0.743835758
```

How to operate the `DT` to set the duplicated values of `y` in each group of `x` into `NA` through the `data.table`'s semantics. The following is the desired result.

```
    x    y           z
 1: F    a 0.646902839
 2: F <NA> 0.394225758
 3: F <NA> 0.618501814
 4: F    b 0.476891136
 5: F <NA> 0.136097186
 6: F <NA> 0.067384386
 7: M    a 0.129152617
 8: M <NA> 0.393117930
 9: M <NA> 0.002582699
10: M    b 0.620205954
11: M <NA> 0.764414018
12: M <NA> 0.743835758
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` to find duplicated values in each `x` and replace them with `NA`.

```
library(data.table)
DT[, y := replace(y, duplicated(y), NA), x]
DT

#    x    y       z
# 1: F    a 0.64690
# 2: F <NA> 0.39423
# 3: F <NA> 0.61850
# 4: F    b 0.47689
# 5: F <NA> 0.13610
# 6: F <NA> 0.06738
# 7: M    a 0.12915
# 8: M <NA> 0.39312
# 9: M <NA> 0.00258
#10: M    b 0.62021
#11: M <NA> 0.76441
#12: M <NA> 0.74384
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>%
     group_by(x) %>%
     mutate(y = replace(y, duplicated(y), NA))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT[DT[, .I[duplicated(y)], x]$V1, y := NA]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
DT$y[duplicated(DT[, c('x', 'y'), with = FALSE])] <- NA
```